# Javascript - date range validation

Tags: javascript, date, range

i've a form user can enter any date , but i want to set a date range validation . for example: from 1-12-2012 to 1-1-2013 and the system can't accept any date from user that not in the range.. i've tried this javascript code but it doesn't give me any alert even when date not in range ..

this is part of my form :

```
 echo "<tr><th bgcolor='FF6600'> Date <font size='4' color='red'>* </font></th>
        <td> <input type='date' name='v2' value=''   ></td></tr>";


echo "<tr><th bgcolor='FF6600'> Time <font size='4' color='red'>* </font></th>
        <td> <input type='time' name='v3' value=''   ></td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><th bgcolor='FF6600'> Place <font size='4' color='red'>* </font></th>
        <td> <input type='text' name='v4' value=''   ></td></tr>";
```

and this is the javascript code

```
    <script language="javascript">

    function validation(form)
 {

 var v2 = document.getElementById('v2');
 var date = v2.value;
 if ( (v2 > new date('12/12/2012')) && 
    (v2 < new date('1/1/2013')) ){
    // date is in your valid range
     return true;
} else {
    // date is not in your valid range

    alert("date is not in valid range")
    return false;
}


}

    </script>
```

Comment: Please update your post with a [_specific question_](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: What error message is your javascript console giving you? You should cast the inputs you get if you want to compare them with date type values.

Comment: @cheesemacfly it's not an error message i got ! i've said that i didn't get anything thats means the code doen't work

Comment: For example if you use Chrome as a web browser, you don't get any error message in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 8):

To compare dates, you should be using the unix timestamp, and right now the first date you're getting from the value is a string, and you can't compare that against date objects?

Make sure you have timestamps in unix time, and then compare those:

```
function validation(form) {
    var v2 = document.getElementById('v2'),
      date = new Date(v2.value),
      d1   = date.getTime(),
      d2   = new Date('12/12/2012').getTime(),
      d3   = new Date('1/1/2013').getTime();

   if (d1 > d2 || d1 < d3) {
       return true;
   }else{
       alert("date is not in valid range")
   }
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand ur point , u mean in the database or where ? how to make sure i've timestamps in unix time?

Comment: [getTime() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) used in above sample returns unix time - the number of milliseconds between Jan 1, 1970 and the specified date. @annalord

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function like this:

```
function checkMyDateWithinRange(myDdate){
    var startDate = new Date(2012, 11, 1);
    var endDate = new Date(2012, 0, 1);     
    if (startDate < myDate && myDate < endDate) {
       return true; 
    }
   return false;
}
```

and test any date like calling this function:

```
var inputDate= document.getElementById('tbDate'),
date = new Date(inputDate.value);
if(!checkMyDateWithinRange(date)){
    alert('Date is not in range!!!');
}
```

Here is [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5GQfe/)

Comment: so i've to make two functions in javascript?

Comment: thank u, but what about calling the function ? should i put it like this onsubmit = "return validation(form); "